# How to calculate min value of 4 EditTexts in Android?

Tags: java, android

This is an app.
I have 4 EditTexts. which the user enter the number.
There is a min button.

When the user clicks on the min button, it should calculate the minimum of the 4 numbers that were entered by the users.

Comment: what have you tried ? Have you successfully get the text from editText ?

Comment: I figured out that part. i'm stuck in getting the result and showing it in the textview.

Comment: post the code so we can help

Comment: This sounds like homework.

Comment: I figured it out and yes this is an assignment.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Collections.min`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Collections.html#min(java.util.Collection%3C?%20extends%20T%3E)):

```
List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>()
numbers.add(...) // parse your text to int

int minimum = Collections.min(numbers);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to get values from 4 EditText, then parse String to Int

```
    int num1, num2, num3, num4;
    try {
        num1 = Integer.parseInt(editText1.getText().trim().toString());
        num2 = Integer.parseInt(editText2.getText().trim().toString());
        num3 = Integer.parseInt(editText3.getText().trim().toString());
        num4 = Integer.parseInt(editText4.getText().trim().toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Handle error here
    }
```

You can easily find min from the integers then

```
textView.setText(String.valueOf(min))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
min.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
         List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>(); 
         numbers.add(Integer.parseInt(editText1.getText().trim().toString()));
         numbers.add(Integer.parseInt(editText2.getText().trim().toString()));
         numbers.add(Integer.parseInt(editText3.getText().trim().toString()));
         numbers.add(Integer.parseInt(editText4.getText().trim().toString())); 
         min.setText(String.valueOf(Collections.min(numbers)));} 
});
```